# Symfony2 and Doctrine2 - Set onDelete

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities:

Manuscript and Tasks.

In the tasks table, I have the manuscript id and some extra data.
Also, in the tasks entity I have

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Manuscript")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="manuscript_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 **/
private $manuscript;
```

But I would like to delete the specific task when deleting the menuscript.

When trying to delete the manuscript, I am getting:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

IS it possible to do this with the onDelete, or should I delete the task manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by adding:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="manuscript", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $task;
```

In the manuscript entity.